# about istream_iterator, i don't know why

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a file named "wy.txt", it has some integers like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I use `istream_iterator<int>` to read the file, and use `copy()` to output the data to stdout stream.

then I use the same `istream_iterator<int>` to construct a `vector`named `v`, but the size of `v` is 1, do you know why?

This is my code:

```
    ifstream file("wy.txt");
    istream_iterator<int> fileStream(file);
    istream_iterator<int> eof;

    // output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    copy(fileStream, eof, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); 
    cout<<endl;

    vector<int> v(fileStream, eof);
    // output: 1
    cout<<v.size()<<endl;
   // output: 1
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int & t){cout<<t<" ";});
    cout<<endl;
```

Edit:

I have change my code to:

```
    ifstream file("wy.txt");
    istream_iterator<int> fileStream(file);
    istream_iterator<int> eof;

    copy(fileStream, eof, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout<<endl;
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file.clear();
    vector<int> v(fileStream, eof); 
    cout<<v.size()<<endl;
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int & t){cout<<t<" ";});
```

...but it has the same problem.

Comment: Did you clear the EOF state on the file then rewind it?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't reset the stream state, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Look up the `clear` method of `iostream`.

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing an `istream_iterator<int>` behaves like extracting `int` from the associated file:

```
int myInt;
myInt = *fileStream; // same as file >> myInt;
```

This also means that you actually extracted the file's content. You have to set the input cursor at the beginning again:

```
file.clear();  // clear the EOF flag
file.seekg(0);
```

Comment: Input iterators (such as those of ifstreams) are not capable of going backwards.  Resetting just file pointer won't work

Answer (score 0):

Resetting just file pointer won't work

Clear all ifstream's internal error state flags states using `clear`. Then use `seekg`

```
istream_iterator<int> fileStream(file);
istream_iterator<int> eof;
copy(fileStream, eof, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); 
cout<<endl;
file.clear();
file.seekg(0);
vector<int> v(fileStream, eof);
cout<<v.size()<<endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, can we make a friend?